# Control space between paragraph and table in LaTeX

Tags: tables, spacing

I have large white space between paragraph and table in a LaTeX file, see the following figure.

[image]

how to control this space?

MWE is uploaded in this link [MWE](https://www.mediafire.com/?5vpp6aqcnpd3b3t)

the paper should not exceed 1 page

Comment: Do you know that vertical spaces around floats are stretchable? Do you have a full page with text around it?

Comment: No. how to do that?

Comment: I mean, LaTeX controls it. If you think that now it is too big, later, with more content it could be smaller. Don't worry about it now. Finish your text and then you can think about modifying vertical spaces and fine tune formating.

Comment: it is only 1 page abstract and i need to control it

Comment: So, if it is only one page and one table, try to use negative vertical space `\vspace{-1cm}`. But this is not the right way to control this.

Comment: \vspace{-1cm} not working

Comment: `\vspace*{-1cm}` or bigger.

Comment: Try to use \raggedbottom in your preamble. Or make your tabular/array nonfloat (e.g. use a center rather than a table environment. You still can have captions as if it were a table.

Comment: '\vspace*{-1cm}' or bigger also not working

Comment: Something like `\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{-1cm}`

Comment: \setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{-1cm}  also not working ! what is the wrong? @karlkoeller

Comment: Probably a MWE can help, in this case...

Comment: As karlkoeller says we need to see your code.

Comment: @AndrewSwann done

Comment: `dccpaper.cls` is a custom class not on CTAN, and neither is `citesort` (which I doubt is relevant).  However, with those commented out (or replaced with `article`, respectively), the amount of content you have in your MWE yet has LaTeX place the table above the text.  When I manually push the table down (`[b]`), there is more space than in your picture.  Please post an MWE that actually and portably demonstrates your problem. :-)

Comment: `citesort` _is_ on ctan, in `obsolete/macros/latex209` (it dates from 1991).  it _could_ be relevant (it's based on `cite`, and that's had spacing fixes in the intervening 22 years(!).  i guess we need to know what you're using `citesort` for; comments in the file suggest it's to allow line breaks in long lists of citations (which doesn’t tally with my image of what you’re writing...)

Comment: @SeanAllred sorry but what is MWE? and how to post it?

Comment: Oh! My apologies—a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) is the simplest document that reproduces your issue—something that we can compile on our end and tinker with to find a solution.

Comment: You need to make a complete document that shows the problem, but if you are making a 1 page abstract you probably should not be using the table environment, the sole purpose of which is to allow latex to move the content to help with page breaking.

Comment: @SeanAllred  MWE has been added in the post

Comment: If you really just have one page in your paper there is no nead for a floating table with caption. Delete the `table`-environment and so prevent your table from floating. If you really need a caption, use package `capt-of`. You can set the vertical space using `\vspace{<length>}`. I just noticed that @DavidCarlisle suggested the same.

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 6):

To reduce the spacing, you can simply add `h` as a float specifier for your `table` environment, that is change the line

```
\begin{table}
```

to

```
\begin{table}[h]
```

Then, if you want to reduce it a bit more, add a line (adjust `-5pt` to fit your needs)

```
\vspace*{-5pt}
```

just before the beginning of the `table`.

MWE

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% One Column
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 \documentclass[smallabstract,smallcaptions]{dccpaper}

\usepackage{epsfig}
%\usepackage{citesort}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{url}
%\usepackage{placeins}


\newlength{\figurewidth}
\newlength{\smallfigurewidth}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% One Column
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setlength{\smallfigurewidth}{2.75in}
\setlength{\figurewidth}{6in}

\begin{document}

\title
{\large
\textbf{ minimal working example (MWE)  \\
}
}


\author{%
Khaled  $^{\ast}$ and  Sean Allred $^{\dag}$\\[0.5em]
{\small\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c}
School of Computer Science, laTeX University \\
\url{{someting}@stackexchange.com}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}\end{minipage}}
}


\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}

Invented by Adobe Systems and perfected over 20 years, Portable Document Format (PDF) is now an open standard for electronic document exchange maintained by the International Organization for Standardization (ISO). When you convert documents, forms, graphics, and web pages to PDF, they look just like they would if printed. But unlike printed documents, PDF files can contain clickable links and buttons, form fields, video, and audio — as well as logic to help automate routine business processes. When you share a PDF file, virtually anyone can read it using free Adobe Reader® software or the Adobe Reader mobile app.

Invented by Adobe Systems and perfected over 20 years, Portable Document Format (PDF) is now an open standard for electronic document exchange maintained by the International Organization for Standardization (ISO). When you convert documents, forms, graphics, and web pages to PDF, they look just like they would if printed. But unlike printed documents, PDF files can contain clickable links and buttons, form fields, video, and audio — as well as logic to help automate routine business processes. When you share a PDF file, virtually anyone can read it using free Adobe Reader® software or the Adobe Reader mobile app.Invented by Adobe Systems and perfected over 20 years, Portable Document Format (PDF) is now an open standard for electronic document exchange maintained by the International Organization for Standardization (ISO). When you convert documents, forms, graphics, and web pages to PDF, Invented by Adobe Systems and perfected over 20 years, Portable Document Format (PDF) is now an open standard for electronic document exchange maintained by the International Organization for Standardization (ISO). When you convert documents, forms. When you convert documents, forms, graphics, and web pages to PDF, they look just like they would if printed.When you convert documents, forms.

\vspace*{-5pt}
\begin{table}[h]
  \scriptsize\centering
  \caption{Compression of several languages text using different compressors}
    \begin{tabular}{|ccccccccc|}
    \hline
    Language & Corpus & Size  & Bzip2 & ABC2.4 & Gzip  & PPMD& CS-PPM& BS-PPM \\
     &(bytes) & (bpc) & (bpc) & (bpc) &(bpc)&(bpc)&(bpc)&(bpc) \\
    \hline
    Arabic & BACC & 56633170 & 1.45  & 1.38  & 2.14  & 1.83  & 1.38  & \textbf{1.34} \\
    \hline
    Armenian & HC & 36700160 & 1.56  & 1.37  & 2.39  & 1.69  & 1.18  & \textbf{1.17} \\
    \hline
    Chinese & LCMC  & 4555457 & 2.65  & 2.57  & 3.47  & 2.49  & \textbf{2.37}  & 2.46 \\
    \hline
    English & Brown & 5998528 & 2.46  & 2.29  & 3.16  & 2.23  & 2.15  & \textbf{2.10} \\
    \hline
    English & LOB   & 5877271 & 2.43  & 2.27  & 3.14  & 2.21  & 2.13  & \textbf{2.08} \\
    \hline
    Persian & Hamshahri & 41567603 & 1.53  & 1.38  & 2.22  & 1.75  & \textbf{1.20}   & 1.26 \\
    \hline
    Russian & HC & 52428800 & 1.52  & 1.31  & 2.45  & 1.73  & \textbf{1.12}  & 1.12 \\
    \hline
    Welsh & CEG & 6169422 & 2.55  & 2.34  & 3.19  & 2.30   & 2.20   & \textbf{2.14} \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%

\end{table}%



\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]